# Stick to top then drop in css - [I have example site]

Tags: javascript, css

[image]I've just discovered this [great site](http://art.sy/) about art. I am curious about they can make the left header stick to the top then stop and specific place. Due to my understanding the `position: absolute;` should stick on top all the time, shouldn't it ?

Do we need any javascript or just only CSS to make the same thing ? Provided example is gonna be awesome.

Comment: Wow, I like the effect for invitation ("request invite" button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it appears to use JS to create that effect. The easiest way to tell is to hit Inspect Element in Chrome/Chromium, then scroll past the article - notice how the inline `position` property changes as you scroll. That can only happen via JS.

More than that, it's hard to say, because all of their scripts are minified, but I assume it uses [`jQuery.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)'s callback to detect which article is showing and then based on that triggers the fixed/absolute style swap to allow the headers to scroll or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how it exactly works if you inspect the element and then scroll down.

It's `absolute` until you've scrolled at about 90px, then it changes the `position` into `static`. 
Static causes the element to float on the page.

Answer (score 1):

this [Way Points plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/)  is exactly what I think you are looking for .  It uses jquery to change positioning from absolute to fixed based on where the user is scrolling

you can not accomplish this with only css, you are going to need some javascript of jQuery to monitor the user scrolling

of course you could write the script on your own to detect the scrolling and manually change the positioning , but if you don't have that much experience (since you didn't already know that was javascript - or that absolute positioning will not stick the element to the top)  defiantly use a plugin and get use to how that works first.